# Environment for my freezing aliens

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, creature-design, science-fiction

So I am designing my aliens flash-freeze-on-target mechanism and now I am wondering what would be the more practical use for these flash freezing powers, as a predator or prey.

These creatures are as intelligent and curious as humans, and as social as rats. They have a tube and pod net system under the skin connect to dozens of small holes to suck in the air. They pressurize this air till it's a liquid then can release it out causing it to become cold and flash-freeze the target on which it is sprayed.

An offensive application would be to target prey which can fly away fast so flash-freezing would stop them at once leaving them ready to be eaten.

A defensive application would be to flash-freeze attacking predators and get away before being eaten.

So basically what I'm asking is what would be the most efficient use of these powers: offensive or defensive? predator or prey?

Comment: A lot of people read these.  A lot of people are still irritated by obvious typos ("king of prey", "endurence", "preditor application") especially those that spell check would catch - including the spellcheck on this site which tried to correct those two misspellings!    Try cleaning this up.

Comment: @Will You could always take the initiative and fix those typos yourself.

Comment: @Will sorry I was in a rush and had to do something after I had started this so I tried to do it real fast I'll try to fix them buddy

Comment: What, exactly, is being asked?  The kind of prey this creature would feed on?  How prey would be captured?  There isn't a question mark anywhere and I'm not sure what "so what is more logical" refers to.  And what "hard-science" are you asking for?  That tag means, "mathematics and authoritative sources must be provided for valid answers."  What hard science about a non-existent creature are you expecting?

Comment: @JBH which is a better and more efficient use for the freezing ability, as offensive or denfensive. A tool for a predator or prey

Comment: Please edit your question with the explanation.  It's difficult for participants to comb through comments for clarification.

Comment: @JBH okay then dude I will

Comment: @sphennings The first couple times, but if its the 6th time you posted and you still can't figure out the spell-check....

Comment: @kingledion I'm not saying that posters shouldn't strive to improve the quality of their posts but if you have over 1k rep this is a problem that can be fixed instead of just complaining about it.

Comment: @sphennings: give a man a fish and he is hungry tomorrow.  Teach a man to fish and he will never be hungry.

Comment: @Will If you write a meaningful edit description you can do both at once. If you find yourself regularly editing the same poster's posts then in addition to making the edits go ahead and remind them that they should put more effort into editing their posts before posting them.

Comment: I took the challenge of editing this post to make it readable. I could make because I had the leisure of being at home and with plenty of time. Should I have been in my office in the usual rush the task would have defeated me. Having translated patents from German to my native language, I dare to give an advice to the OP: until you master mimicking the stream-of-consciousness, refrain from writing questions in that style (better, refrain in any case if your goal is clarity)

Comment: @L.Dutch okay then thank you I appreciate it greatly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things frozen to cryogenic temperatures are brittle and hard, and moreover they are damn cold!

**If you use the freezing for attacking/preying**: your target will become a lump of really cold ice, brittle as glass and too cold to be eaten. Your predator will have to wait patiently until the prey unfreezes, as any attempt to carry it around would shatter it to icy dust. Unless your predator is a vacuum cleaner feeding on ice dust, this is a dead end.

**If you use the freezing for defending**: it is something similar to the ink used by cephalopods. Even though the spray may miss the target, the resulting cloud of fog, resulting from the sudden cooling of the surrounding atmosphere will allow the animal to seek refuge, while the poor predator is disoriented.

Comment: Thank you very much, and could something like this develop human intelligence?

Comment: @Amoeba That looks like a separate question worthy of its own post.